# How to show the second image of the product and the last one? PrestaShop

Tags: image, product, prestashop-1.7

I would like to show the second product image on hover for some products.
And the last one image for a specific category.

I tried to do it with this, but I'm using the v. 1.7.5.1

```
<a href="{$product.link|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" class="product_img_link" title="{$product.name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}">
    {assign var='productimg' value=Tools::getProductsImgs($product.id_product)}                         
    {if isset($productimg[0]) && isset($productimg[1])}
        <img class="img_0"  src="{$link->getImageLink($product.link_rewrite,$product.id_product|cat:"-"|cat:$productimg[0].id_image, 'home_default')}" alt="{$product.legend|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" {if isset($homeSize)} width="{$homeSize.width}" height="{$homeSize.height}"{/if} />
        <img class="img_1" src="{$link->getImageLink($product.link_rewrite,$product.id_product|cat:"-"|cat:$productimg[1].id_image, 'home_default')}"alt="{$product.legend|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" {if isset($homeSize)} width="{$homeSize.width}" height="{$homeSize.height}"{/if} />                           
    {else}
        <img src="{$link->getImageLink($product.link_rewrite, $product.id_image, 'home_default')|escape:'html'}" alt="{$product.legend|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" {if isset($homeSize)} width="{$homeSize.width}" height="{$homeSize.height}"{/if} />                   
    {/if}
    {if isset($product.new) && $product.new == 1}<span class="new">{l s='New'}</span>{/if}
</a>
```

When I refresh the page I see only the title "New collection" with the section opened and not closed. Nothing else, all the page empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Tools::getProductsImgs" don't exist.

Try this :

```
{assign var='productimg' value=Image::getImages($language.id, $product.id)}                         
{if isset($productimg[0]) && isset($productimg[1])}
    <img class="img_0"  src="{$link->getImageLink($product.link_rewrite,$product.id_product|cat:"-"|cat:$productimg[0].id_image, 'home_default')}" alt="{$product.legend|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" {if isset($homeSize)} width="{$homeSize.width}" height="{$homeSize.height}"{/if} />
    <img class="img_1" src="{$link->getImageLink($product.link_rewrite,$product.id_product|cat:"-"|cat:$productimg[1].id_image, 'home_default')}"alt="{$product.legend|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" {if isset($homeSize)} width="{$homeSize.width}" height="{$homeSize.height}"{/if} />
{else}
    <img src="{$link->getImageLink($product.link_rewrite, $product.id_image, 'home_default')|escape:'html'}" alt="{$product.legend|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" {if isset($homeSize)} width="{$homeSize.width}" height="{$homeSize.height}"{/if} />                   
{/if}
```

Regards